# NSURLSession with custom authentication challenge?

Tags: ios, authentication, restful-authentication, nsurlsession

Our application makes use of RESTful service calls using `NSURLSession`.  The calls themselves are routed through a reverse proxy, to aide in session management, security, etc. on the backend.  The only problem we're having is related to authentication.  When a user attempts to access a protected resource -- either through a browser or a REST call -- and they are *not authenticated*, the reverse proxy displays an HTML login page.

The problem is, we'd like to leverage `NSURLSession`'s ability to handle authentication challenges automatically.  However, `NSURLSession` is unable to recognize that we're getting back an authentication challenge, because no HTTP 401 or other error code is being returned to the client.  The reverse proxy sends back a 200, because the HTML was delivered successfully.  We're able to recognize that it is the login page by inspecting the HTML within the client, but we'd like to be able to handle the authentication using a custom `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`, if at all possible, so that `NSURLSession` can retry requests after authentication is successful.

Is there any way for us to recognize that we're getting back a login page within our `completionHandler` and tell `NSURLSession` that we're really getting back an authentication challenge?  Or does `NSURLSession` require that we receive back an HTTP error code (401, etc.)

Comment: Besides the negative answer below, did you figure out a way to get NSURLAuthenticationChallenge for your situation? Are there good solutions for the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication challenges are triggered by the WWW-Authenticate header in a 40x response.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html) :

> The URL loading system classes do not call their delegates to handle request challenges unless the server response contains a WWW-Authenticate header. Other authentication types, such as proxy authentication and TLS trust validation do not require this header.

Unfortunately the proxy authentication referred to above does not apply in your reverse proxy/accelerator scenario.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of possibilities come to mind.

1. If you're using the delegate rendition of `NSURLSession`, you might be able to detect the redirect to the authentication failure page via `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` method `willPerformHTTPRedirection`.

   You can probably also detect the redirect by examining the task's `currentRequest.URL` and see if a redirect happened there, too. As the documentation says, `currentRequest` "is typically the same as the initial request (`originalRequest`) except when the server has responded to the initial request with a redirect to a different URL."
2. Assuming that the RESTful service generally would not be returning HTML, you can look at the `NSURLResponse`, confirm that it's really a `NSHTTPURLResponse` subclass, and then look at `allHeaderFields` to confirm whether `text/html` appears in the `Content-Type` of the response. This obviously only works if the authentication page returns a `Content-Type` that includes `text/html` and the rest of your responses don't (e.g. they're `application/json` or something like that).

   Anyway, that might look like:

   ```
   NSString *contentType = [self headerValueForKey:@"Content-Type" response:response];

   if ([contentType rangeOfString:@"text/html"].location != NSNotFound) {
       // handle it here
   }
   ```

   Where, `headerValueForKey` might be defined as follows:

   ```
   - (NSString *)headerValueForKey:(NSString *)searchKey response:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {
       if (![response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
           return nil;

       NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *) response allHeaderFields];

       for (NSString *key in headers) {
           if ([searchKey caseInsensitiveCompare:key] == NSOrderedSame) {
               return headers[key];
           }
       };

       return nil;
   }
   ```
3. At worst, you could detect the HTML response and parse it using something like HPPLE and programmatically detect the authentication HTML response.

   See Wenderlich's article [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

Frankly, though, I would prefer to see a REST response to report the authentication error with a REST response (or a proper authentication failure challenge or a non 200 response) rather than a redirect to a HTML page. If you have an opportunity to change the server response, that would be my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply setting the username and password to the authorization header of NSMutableURLRequest as such.

```
NSString *authorizationString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",user, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding]; 

[yourRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authorizationString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

This should work.

Comment: If you had read the question, you would see I am not performing Basic or Digest authentication.  Rather, I am using HTML forms-based authentication.  If I were performing Basic authentication, I would get back a 401 and would be able to respond to it easily.  However, I get back a 200 because the login page HTML is returned successfully.  That is the root of the problem.

Comment: I understand that. This answer is for when you get back 200.

Comment: You're not simple talking about just posting to a HTML form, right? Because if that were the case no custom nsurlauthentication would be necessary. You would just post your username and password to the pages that require it.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a simple POST.  However, doing it manually within the task would cause us to lose the benefit of task replay provided by NSURLSession.  If we were using Basic authentication, NSURLSession would recognize the auth challenge and then replay the task when the authentication was successful.  We would lose that if we manually detected the login page and did a manual POST.  My question is, can we recognize the login page and then make NSURLSession recognize that as an authentication challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an HTML Parser library (like https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader).

Then in the completion handler block, you can evaluate the response to check if it is an HTML page, and if it contains a login form.

I don't know this library, but I guess you can use it like this:

```
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:responseObjectFromServer];
HTMLNode *node = [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"form.login"];
if(node) {
    // Perform second NSURLSession call with login data
}
```